# Retrieving readings from a website and input in laravel

Tags: laravel

So from the guidelines given in the comment section, my progress so far is as shown below, can someone tell me whether I'm doing it right?

Under the kernel.php, I created a task schedule for every minute,

```
 $schedule->exec('public/js/jsonp.js')->everyMinute();
```

basically I want to execute the jsonp.js that I created every minute.

jsonp.js

```
var public_key = 'LQL4w78xVwSmbGoapmj3';
 $.ajax({
   url: 'http://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
   jsonp: 'callback',
   cache: true,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   data: {
     page: 1
   },
   success: function(response) {
     // response will be a javascript

     console.log(response[0].temperature);
   }
 });
```

Unfortunately, the console doesn't display the temperature value taken every minute. Can someone guide me in telling which part of my code is wrong and how should I do it instead? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know how to retrieve data from Sparkfun, give a look to the [documentation](http://phant.io/docs/output/http) .

Using [Laravel's task scheduling](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling) you can execute a task for example every 10 minutes. This task has to retrieve data from Sparkfun using PHP Curl and then insert resulting data into database.

Comment: Thank you for the guideline, I made some changes to the question, mind guiding me on which part I did wrongly? Sorry, I'm actually fairly new in this.